# Cannot resolve method in Picasso method .load

Tags: android, picasso, image-loading, colordrawable

Picasso image loading library shows error while use with:

```
ColorDrawable cd = new ColorDrawable(ContextCompat.getColor(mContext,R.color.light_thirty_alpha));

 Picasso.with(mContext)
                .load(cd)
                .fit().centerCrop()
                .transform(new RoundedTransformation(5, 0))
                .error(cd)
                .placeholder(cd)
                .into(imageView_ovelay_slider);
```

It is showing **error** that cannot resolve method .load(colorDrawable). I already knows that it is not accept colorDrawable but I am asking can we cast colorDrawable to something else that accepts by .load().

Comment: I already knows that it will does not accept colorDrawable in its load method that's why i have asked question how to deal with it if i want to use colorDrawable. So why downVote? Explain @Apurva

Comment: You cannot use `ColorDrawable`. If you want to use it, you can fork the project add the new method and add the code to handle it. That's the only solution if you want to use `ColorDrawable`.

Answer (score 0):

If you look at the [source code](https://github.com/square/picasso/blob/master/picasso/src/main/java/com/squareup/picasso/Picasso.java), you will see that, Picasso's `load` method can accept any one of the following parameters:

- [Uri](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/Uri.html)
- String
- [File](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/io/File.html)
- int (Resource Id)

It does not accept `ColorDrawable`

Answer (score 0):

**.load** method doesn't accepts **ColorDrawable** as parameter. Look at the official documentation for accepted parameters.

1. load(**File** file) - image request using the **specified image file.**
2. load(**int** resourceId) - mage request using the specified **drawable resource ID.**
3. load(**String** path) - image request using the **specified path.**
4. load(**android.net.Uri** uri) - image request using the **specified URI.**

http://square.github.io/picasso/2.x/picasso/

Answer (score 0):

Solution was so easy finally found by using

solution 1(worked & tested):

```
ColorDrawable cd = new ColorDrawable(ContextCompat.getColor(mContext,R.color.light_thirty_alpha));
        Picasso.with(mContext)
                .load(String.valueOf(cd))
                .fit().centerCrop()
                .transform(new RoundedTransformation(5, 0))
                .error(cd)
                .placeholder(cd)
                .into(imageView_ovelay_slider);
```

solution 2(worked & tested):

alternate way i found is to create shape drwable.xml file with radius.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<item>
    <shape android:shape="rectangle">
        <stroke
            android:width="0dp"
            android:height="0dp"
            android:color="@color/transparent" />

        <!-- apply button background transparent, full opacity -->
        <solid android:color="@color/box" />
        <corners android:radius="2.5dp" />

        <padding android:bottom="2dp"
            android:left="4dp"
            android:right="4dp"
            android:top="2dp" />
    </shape>
</item>
```

and use it as background drawable. Thank you @Prerak Sola & Alok